# Facebook Long Lived Token Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is what fb degugger says

App ID: 
MY_APP_ID : APP_NAME

Metadata:   []

User ID:

USER_ID : NAME

Issued: Unknown

Expires:    1366920000 (in about an hour)

Valid:  True

Origin: Web

Scopes: create_note manage_pages photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update user_groups video_upload

Comment: So.. how is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

at first generate a temporary token by javascript sdk

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status=='connected') {
    if (response.authResponse.accessToken) {
    var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
           ............rest of the codes
```

then in server side extend your token using curl call to the following url to get final token -
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_Client_Secret&fb_exchange_token=your_temporary_token

hope this solves what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow the steps described on this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/?

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&fb_exchange_token=ORIGINAL_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN