# Facebook user access token expired at unix time

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a joomla module which shows facebook group/page wall feeds by using Graph Api.For this Graph Api, call is made with a access token created by my facebook application.I generate this token by the following way, look my 3rd answer in this question -

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222168/facebook-long-lived-token-not-working/16345169#16345169)

now in past couple of days one user of my module getting following error -

```
Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1370094151. The current unix time is 1370376671.
```

I will ask that user if he changed his facebook account password or removed authorization from my application by which he generated access token, If for these reasons the error shown.but it's most likely that 2 months just passed.I know fb long lived user token expired in 2 months.so this may be a reason.Is there way i can generate ever lasting token which don't expire? i found some posts regarding token expiration but i could not come into conclusion.
Any solution are welcome...

---

1. I do understand that user should be redirected to my access token generation page once their token expired.
2. Also i know that a valid 60 days token can be extended another 60 days by sending the user again to the javascript sdk login flow.

The problem is that my joomla(php cms) module used by many users in their sites to show wall feed which is done by graph api call using their access token.this token they generate coming to my access token generation page in my site and token is generated by js sdk login flow and server side token exchange(sdk initiated  with my fb application).

> Now one user suddenly sees a access token expiring error in the module
>   located in their site as i said above, and its frustrating coz his
>   website visitors also sees that error instead of wall feed.So if there
>   any way i can code in my module so that access token extends
>   automatically bef4 expire date or at the time of expire.

So these are all my scenarios, i must need to extend automatically.So any one here help me by suggesting ways in coding perspective and all the ways or any alternatives.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When user changes the password, that has **NO** impact on your app. That's the purpose of OAuth, completely decoupling user credentials and app authorization.

FB Tokens do expire. Even those "long lived tokens". You need to exchange an access token to a so called "long lived token" immediately after you have been given the access token or prior using it.

You may do this as often as you want, BUT: once the access token *has* expired, no access at all is possible any longer and you need to sent the user through the complete OAuth flow again.

An expired access token is completely useless. That's by design in FB.

Comment: So max expire date of a user token is two months.no way to  make never expire.

Comment: Your are able to retrieve a "long lived token" within that 60 days. This long lived token then is valid another 60 days. If you do that every time you access, you have "unlimited" access unless the time of 60 days has expired since the last renewal. This isn't THAT complicated, isn't it?

Comment: So how do i retrieve another 60 days token from my current 60 days token which still valid/expired? I found that calling graph api exchange token url will work with only short lived access token to extend expiry date.help me all ways whether its server or client side call to extend the expiry date  while my current 60 days token is valid/expired.Thanks in advance